# Help understanding why my derivative is wrong?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I need to differentiate $(-x^\frac{1}{\delta} -y^\frac{1}{\delta})^\delta$ with respect to $x$ in order to find a more complex derivative. However, online derivative calculators are all giving something different than what I derived (I wanted to make sure mine's right so I checked with them).

I got the derivative $\delta (\frac{-1}{\delta} x^{\frac{1}{\delta}-1}) (-x^\frac{1}{\delta} -y^\frac{1}{\delta})^{\delta-1}$

I derived this by substituting $u = x^\frac{1}{\delta}$ in the usual manner.

However, every online calculator I use gives the following answer (note the -1 in brackets which gives an additional term):

[image]

Is anyone able to explain to me why I'm wrong (or why the online calculators are wrong)?

Comment: You may be mis-entering the expression in the online calculator. [Here is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+(-x%5E(1%2Fd)-y%5E(1%2Fd))%5Ed) what Wolfram Alpha returns.

Comment: I didn't check this, but perhaps the online calculators are calculating the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ for something like $y=(-x^{1/\delta}-y^{1/\delta})^\delta$.

Comment: That could definitely be it. If I don't use $y$ it now says "steps not currently supported"

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, just wondering, is wolfram alpha always correct? Or is it prone to errors. I ask because I'd like to check more complicated derivatives.

Comment: @Patty No computer software is *always correct*, and that includes WA. That said, it does a fairly good job at answering correctly, provided you ask the right question *with* the right syntax (which is not always obvious).